# How to call onChange event using FindComponent?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

If I'm searching a component like this :

```
TMemo(FindComponent('mymemoname'));
```

How do I call the `OnChange` event of this `TMemo`? The example below won't work :

```
TMemo(FindComponent('mymemoname')).Change();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Change()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.Change) method is `protected`, so to call it directly like you are trying to, you would need to use an accessor class to grant access to the calling scope, eg:

```
type
  TMemoAccess = class(TMemo)
  end;

TMemoAccess(TMemo(FindComponent('mymemoname'))).Change();
```

Otherwise, you can just call the `OnChange` handler directly instead:

```pascal
var TheMemo := TMemo(FindComponent('mymemoname'));
TheMemo.OnChange(TheMemo);
```